# Custom AngularJS Directives

Tags: angularjs

I'm going through the Angular course on CodeAcademy and I'm apparently not understanding how a custom directive works. Their help forums are not available right now or else I would have posted there instead. I am trying to create a new angular directive. That's the goal here. The setup that I am using is pointing to an external(html) template. The problem that I am having is when I input data into the attribute outlined in the local directive scope, nothing is showing up on the page. My directive definition is below...

==================================

```
app.directive('programListing', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            show: '=listing'
        }
        templateUrl: 'js/directives/programListing.html'
    };
});
```

==================================

My understanding of this is that I have declared a new directive called 'programListing' and when Angular does it's thing, I can utilize this directive as in my DOM Hierarchy. As a result of having defined a local scope for this directive, I should be able to utilize the "listing" attribute alongside this directive to insert data into it and pull from the object defined in my Controller. Below is the layout of my controller for the view.

==================================

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.program = {
        series: "Sherlock",
        series_img: "img/sherlock.jpg",
        genre: "Crime drama",
        season: 3,
        episode: "The Empty Hearse",
        description: "Two years after his reported Reichenbach Fall demise, Sherlock, who has been cleared of all fraud charges against him, returns with Mycroft's help to a London under threat of terrorist attack. John has moved on and has a girlfriend, Mary Morstan. Sherlock enlists Molly to assist him, but when John is kidnapped by unknown assailants and is rescued by Sherlock and Mary, John returns to help find the terrorists and an underground plot to blow up the Houses of Parliament during an all night sitting on Guy Fawkes Night.",
        datetime: new Date(2014, 11, 31, 21, 00, 00, 00)
    }
}]);
```

==================================

Here is the external HTML template that my directive is pointing to.

==================================

```
<div class="col-md-6">
-h1 class="series"-{{show.series}} -h2 class="episode"-{{show.episode}} -p class="description"-{{show.description}} -/div-
```

==================================

I'm hoping someone can provide some insight to what i'm missing here.

Comment: Something is very wrong with your copy of the external HTML template ... can you please clean it up? Additionally, how do you use the directive?

Comment: Could you please provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your code?

Comment: I figured out the issue but I don't understand why it fixed it. In my index.html(default landing page), I used a script element to reference the directive definition in a .js file. When I put that element in the <head> tag of my HTML markup, it won't work. When I take that element and put it at the bottom of my HTML markup, it works fine.